# Kernel Density Estimation in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kernel-density

I have a list of counts ('y' in the code below), that I am using to plot a probability distribution - so note it is not raw data but really frequencies that I have already calculated which should fall across various bins. A scatter plot and even a histogram (plotted with the bar function) revealed that it was some manner of bimodal distribution. I wanted to be able to fit a pdf to this so I first tried just a sum of gaussians but the curve fitting algorithm in SciPy was unsuccessful in fitting the curve. I then came across Kernel Density Estimation which from what I have read is the best way to achieve this but for some reason, even after putting together code from here at stack overflow from an answer to a similar question and also from a different website, both of which recommended using the gaussian_kde function from scipy.stats, I have so far been unsuccessful in being able to do so. Am I wrong in assuming that I can do this for what I have in the first place? If I am correct, what can I do to get it right?

```
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, n_bins) 
y = np.array(normed_pdf)
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5, label='Sim Data')
plt.hold('on')
kde = gaussian_kde(y, bw_method=0.1 / y.std(ddof=1))
kde.covariance_factor = lambda : .25
kde._compute_covariance()
plt.plot(x, kde(x), 'r-', label='fit')
plt.hold('off')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(prop={'size':10})
plt.show()
```

I know that I might as well use R or GNUPlot or some other tool to do this but I want to be able to do it within Python. Call me a stickler self-contained, consistent code.

Comment: You should never fit your KDE on this preprocessed frequency-data, but on the raw data! I also prefer the kde-tools within statsmodels and scikit-learn. But scipy's will do too (but less powerful tools for hyperparameter-selection).

Comment: Right. So now that I got to know I cannot generate a pdf with kde with the frequency-data, I resigned to re-construct the 'raw-data' from the frequency data.  The frequencies in my case here were really of a range of equally spaced values that I generated with numpy.arange and I just created a new list with the values appearing with those frequencies. Now the gaussian_kde works like a charm. I will try the ones from scikit-learn, I do read everywhere that it is better in some ways. But really, what if I want to fit a curve to data like that? The scipy curve_fit did not work at all!

Comment: I'm not even partially understanding what you are doing and ```did not work at all``` is not a precise error-message. It works well for many people. If you really want help, be way more precise and add code which we can run too.

Comment: It sounds like (as you first tried) you really want to fit the frequency spectrum with one or more Gaussian (or perhaps other shaped) peaks.  I'd suggest pursuing that apprach. You might find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful for this.  There are examples of fitting multiple peaks (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-3-fitting-multiple-peaks-and-using-prefixes) and changing the functional forms of the peaks (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peaked-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: (1) You have one-dimensional data; ie, just one variable, with counts. (2) When you plot a histogram of the data you see two modes. (3) The shapes of the two 'humps' appear to be at least approximately Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Bill. @Newville, Thank you, I will definitely give them a try but since i got KDE working, I'm assuming it will be better than any of them and seems like the more sensible approach. You know at least now I can say that I have learnt numerous ways of fitting data of all thanks to you!

Comment: Given your answer, http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html might also be of interest to you.